# Apache Solr synonyms during querying only

Tags: solr

I want to use a synonym file during querying only (and not during indexing).

Can anyone advise on how to do that?

I'm using Solr 8.5.0.

I was able to get the synonyms to work but only if I did it during indexing, like so:

```
% cat docs/csv/3.csv
id,text
1,happy to be here
2,here is where you want to be
3,aaafoo
4,aaabar
5,bbbfoo

% echo "randomWord => here" > server/solr/configsets/_default/conf/synonyms.txt
% bin/./solr create -c tmpCollection -s 2 -rf 2; bin/./post -c tmpCollection -type text/csv -out yes docs/csv/3.csv
% curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/tmpCollection/select?q=text:randomword"
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":42,
    "params":{
      "q":"text:randomword"}},
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"maxScore":0.28847915,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"2",
        "text":["here is where you want to be"],
        "_version_":1666549776061038592},
      {
        "id":"1",
        "text":["happy to be here"],
        "_version_":1666549777231249408}]
  }}
```

But if I update the synonyms.txt file after creating the index then that change doesn't impact the querying at all.

```
% echo "anotherWord => here" >> server/solr/configsets/_default/conf/synonyms.txt
% curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/tmpCollection/select?q=text:anotherword"
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":10,
    "params":{
      "q":"text:anotherword"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"maxScore":0.0,"docs":[]
  }}
% bin/./solr stop -all; bin/./solr start -e cloud -noprompt
% curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/tmpCollection/select?q=text:anotherword"
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":73,
    "params":{
      "q":"text:anotherword"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"maxScore":0.0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

Just to make sure that that I'm playing around with the right file:

```
% find . -name "synonyms.txt"  |xargs grep -i randomword
./server/solr/configsets/_default/conf/synonyms.txt:randomWord => here
%
```

I thought about just adding the synonyms pre-index but when the added synonyms are a few hundreds, it really slows down the indexing process.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

POST-EDIT: another way to ask this would be:
I have an existing index and all the documents are already in it. I have a new synonyms.txt file that I'd like to attach for query time.

Is that possible? How?

Comment: Share the definition of fieldType for field "text".

Comment: apply the synonym filter at the query time only...while creating the defination of fieldType create index tie and query time...and for the query time only apply the synonym filter.

Comment: @raghu777 the "text" field is just plain text. I show the content of the file indexed and the way it is indexed. Did you mean something else?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti could you please elaborate on the steps? I apologize but I'm new with Solr.

Comment: Perhaps I should ask it in a different way: is it possible to add a synonym file *after* the index had already been created and all the documents were already added to it?

Comment: Yes...but it can be only added to the query time analyzer...if you want it to be for the index time analyzer then you have to reindex the data

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti how can I do that then? Let's assume I have an existing index, how do I get it to "know" a new synonyms.txt file during querying?

Comment: @elkon: you have to create one and pass it to your filter factory and apply the same to your query time analyser of that fieldtype of the field.

Comment: The managed-schema file already has pointers to server/solr/configsets/_default/conf/synonyms.txt in all the field definitions but changing the synonyms.txt file after the indexing and before the querying doesn't have any effect (as I show in the main description). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Example of query time synonym filter,

```
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="text_general" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <!-- Query time synonym filter -->
    <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: Thanks! However I see that these definitions are already there in my managed-schema file.